# Refresh / Reload FileChooser

Tags: python, kivy, filechooser

Currently I'm working with `FileChooser` a lot and I didn't find any mention of refreshing the widget in the [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html). The widget is awesome, but if someone wants to refresh shown files, a movement from current directory is necessary to refresh files.

The problem is when you have a *single* directory as a `rootpath` and inside are only files, therefore no such movement is possible.

My question was how to refresh the widget if I want to avoid any wasteful removing/adding of `FileChooser` and do it as short as possible for a `FileChooser` that is very nested in a `kv` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After I searched `filechooser.py` I found the [code](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/filechooser.py#L671) which is triggered on each movement between directories. Giving the fact the `FileChooserIconView` and `FileChooserListView` inherit from `FileChooserController`, the access to the function is simple and no additional imports are required.

**Let's say we have `filechooser = FileChooserIconView()`:**

`filechooser._update_files()` works well and when is `FileChooser` nested somewhere, it's easy to access it with `id`

For more tweaks `Clock.schedule_interval(filechooser._update_files, t)` may be helpful where you can update your directory content within a reasonable time.

(I add it here, because I found no mention of it, however it may be useful to someone.)

Comment: Just a note, that given _update_files is an internal function, it would be good for somebody to eventually open a feature request with kivy that the function be exposed as part of the api, so it doesn't change in some upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

With ipyfilechooser-0.6 you can use the `refresh()` method to do so. I use it in combination with an upload widget like this:

```py
    chooser = FileChooser()
    upload = w.FileUpload()
    
    def handle_upload(change):
        file_meta = change["new"][0]
        fn = file_meta["name"]
        output = Path(chooser.default_path) / fn  # write to default dir.
        with open(output, mode="wb") as fh:
            fh.write(file_meta["content"])
        print("written file to:", output)
        chooser.refresh()  # refresh file chooser to display newly uploaded file.

   display(chooser, upload)
```