# How to Make Kivy File Chooser auto refresh in python

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, filechooser

So I have been coding this file explorer program. I have coded the copy function so far and the problem I am running into is that after I copy a file to its new directory(i.e. the directory that I am on currently in the filechooser) the file isn't showing up in the the actual filechooser. I am using the icon view and I saw only one mention of this online here:[Refresh / Reload FileChooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36264301/refresh-reload-filechooser) and I tried this method and like the actual _update_files() function is getting executed.(checked it with a couple of print statements) But I am noticing that there is not any change in the actual filechooser.What am i doing wrong here? THANK YOU!!!

> This is the python code that is executed when ever the file is copied. I assigned the actual screen that contains the file chooser to a variable named **MainScreenVar**

```
        for i in range(0, self.execute_data_length):

            if self.execute_data[i][2] == "File" :
                shutil.copy2(self.execute_data[i][1], current_path)
                MainScreenvar = MainScreen()
                return MainScreenvar.ids.filechooser._update_files()
        mycursor.execute("DELETE FROM selection")
        mydb.commit()
```

> This is part of the kivy file:

```
<MainScreen>:
FileChooserIconView:
    id:filechooser
    size_hint:1,.9
    pos_hint:{"top": .9}
    color: 0,0,0,0
```

and the source code for the kivy file chooser is here:
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/_modules/kivy/uix/filechooser.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your code is the line:

```
MainScreenvar = MainScreen()
```

which is creating a new instance of `MainScreen`. This will not be the instance that is displayed in your GUI, so the line:

```
return MainScreenvar.ids.filechooser._update_files()
```

is calling `_update_files()` for a `FileChooserIconView` that is not displayed in your GUI. The solution is to use a reference to the actual `FileChooserIconView` that is in your GUI. Probably something like:

```
MainScreenvar = self.manager.get_screen('main')
```

However, this is only a guess since you haven't provided much of your code. This assumes that your posted code is from a `Screen`, and that the `name` that you provided for `MainScreen` is `main`.

Comment: ohh!!! never realized that. Thanks a lot, worked perfectly. Now the file chooser updates every time I execute a function